# BASH find regex for arbitrary range of numbers in a large number of files

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, find

I am writing a BASH script that, among other things, copies files from one directory to another based on input arguments for the start and end dates. The filenames are of the format `YYYYMMDDhhmmss.jpg`, e.g. `20161230143922.jpg`. I am using `find ... -exec cp {} ...` because there are tens of thousands of files in the source directory. The input arguments are the start and end date in the format `YYYYMMDD`.

I know that I can't do a simple range in the regex like `($startdate..$enddate)`, but I am unable to figure out how to programmatically generate a regex that would work. If I had fewer files I could simply do `cp {$startdate..$enddate} destination`, but alas I don't think that is feasible.

I would like to copy all files between `$startdate` and `$enddate` that fall between the hours of 0500 and 1700. This would include images like `20170102060635.jpg` and `20170104131255.jpg`, but not `20170103010022.jpg`.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

STARTDATE=$1
ENDDATE=$2
FILE_NAME="review-${STARTDATE}-${ENDDATE}.mp4"

if [[ -n "$STARTDATE" ]]; then
  echo "STARTDATE: $STARTDATE"
else
  echo "Invalid start date: '$STARTDATE'"
  echo "Syntax: ./create_time_lapse_date_range.sh <startdate> <enddate>"
  exit
fi

if [[ -n "$ENDDATE" ]]; then
  echo "ENDDATE: $ENDDATE"
else
  echo "Invalid end date: '$ENDDATE'"
  echo "Syntax: ./create_time_lapse_date_range.sh <startdate> <enddate>"
  exit
fi

cd ~/Desktop/test\ timelapse

# Copy relevant files to local directory
find ~/Desktop/originals -regex "???????????????" -exec cp {} ~/Desktop/test\ timelapse/ \;

# Rename files to be sequential serial numbers
find ~/Desktop/test\ timelapse -name "*.jpg" | awk 'BEGIN{ a=0  }{ printf "mv \"%s\" ~/Desktop/\"test\ timelapse/%06d.jpg\"\n", $0, a++ }' | bash

# Generate timelapse video
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i %06d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 25 ${FILE_NAME}
```

Comment: You can make a function, that will split date and time from the filename and compare these to the relevant boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex isn't the best tool for dealing with numerical ranges, so you may need to consider a solution that incorporates some logic outside the regex itself. Something like this:

```
REGEX="([0-9]{8})([0-9]{4})"

for f in ~/Desktop/originals/*.jpg
do
    if [[ $f =~ $regex ]]
    then
        datepart=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        timepart=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}

        #if the DATE part matches
        if (( $STARTDATE <= $datepart )) && (( $datepart <= $ENDDATE ))
        then
            #if the TIME part matches
            if [[ $timepart =~ "(0[5-9]|1[0-7])" ]]
            then
                # copy file ...
            fi
        fi
    fi
done
```

**Pure Regex Solution**

If you really want a pure regex solution, this will help demonstrate the complexity. Here's a regex to find all the files in the 0500 to 1700 timeframe, for dates in January 2017: `^201701\d{2}(0[5-9]|1[0-7])\d{4}\.jpg$`

Notice the regex pattern needed to match times from 0500 to 1700:

`(0[5-9]|1[0-7])`

It's not pretty, and that's with a hardcoded range. To deal with dynamic start and end dates, you would be building a similar pattern dynamically. It could be done, but why use regex for it?

Here's an example, showing what you would need to generate for a date range from 20161225 to 20170114:

`^(201612(2[5-9]|3\d)|201701(0\d|1[0-4]))(0[5-9]|1[0-7])\d{4}\.jpg$`

Comment: @ryan, I added some sample code to my answer to give a more complete solution.